# Google Developer Console - How to setup a Beta Test for a new version of a released App

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We're currently using the public Beta feature of the Google Play Developer console alongside a live released app (though only in one country so far).

For both, we only have one link to the Play Store. If you are located in the country where it is live released, you get the live version - otherwise you get the beta version.
But how can we allow people in live released countries to access our beta app?

Answer (score 0):

In Play Console there's a "Opt-in URL" value when you go to App Releases/Manage Beta/Manage Testers ....a user with live version of app that clicks that link (and agrees to be tester) will get the beta version of the app